# protected field is not accesible from derived class in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I tried to access a protected string from derived class, but its not accessible

```
public class ParentClass
    {
        public string UserName {
            get { return "User Name is accessible to any class under same namespace Skin_File"; }
            set { }
        }
        private string AccountNumber {
            get { return "Not accessible from child class"; }
            set { }
        }
        internal string UserAge {
            get { return "User Age is accesible to child class"; }
            set { }
        }
        protected string PhoneNumber {
            get { return "Accessible only to ParentClass"; }
            set { }
        }
    }
    protected class DerivedClass : ParentClass
    {
        string DerivedUserName = new ParentClass().UserName;
        string  DerivedAccountNumber = new ParentClass().AccountNumber; // Not accessible since that was private
        string DerivedUserAge = new ParentClass().UserAge;
        protected  string DerivedPhoneNumber = new ParentClass().PhoneNumber; // derived class but not accessible
    }
```

Here is the [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KPyXwy) for people who need it.

Comment: downvoters please drop a comment on point to be improved

Comment: What value did you expect `AccountNumber` to have? The new instance's value will be `null` I guess...

Comment: wont it have that value i am returning in the get { } part?

Comment: But you didn't set it, so it is a default I guess (probably `null`).

Comment: @vignesh: Yes, it will.

Comment: Why are you creating instances of the parent class in the derived class?

Answer (score 7):

This:

```
string DerivedPhoneNumber = new ParentClass().PhoneNumber;
```

Creates an instance of `ParentClass` from the and will only have access to public members. As you're inherting `ParentClass`, you **inherit** its protected members as well.

If you want to initialize the value, you need to do so inside your class constructor:

```
protected DerivedClass()
{
    DerivedPhoneNumber = PhoneNumber;
}
```

Although, I don't see the point in declaring another field to store the same number. Access it directly.

Comment: @BartoszKP It doesn't matter. He has an example with `PhoneNumber` and `AccountNumber`.

Comment: Thanks @yuval 
Its not working
You might want to check the fiddle

Comment: @BartoszKP Right, didn't see that it was `private`. Edited the answer.

Comment: @vignesh I've edited my answer. Only `protected` fields will be accessible via derived types.

Comment: for some reasons its not working
here is the fiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/KPyXwy

Comment: It's because PhoneNumber is a Property that you cannot access until the new object is created.

Answer (score 3):

You create an instance of ParentClass. You can't see the protected members.
You have access to it's protected members from the DerivedClass.
You have to just invoke

```
protected  string DerivedPhoneNumber = PhoneNumber;
```

Try the following

```
internal class DerivedClass : ParentClass
{
    string DerivedUserName = new ParentClass().UserName;
    string DerivedUserAge = new ParentClass().UserAge;
    protected string DerivedPhoneNumber;// = PhoneNumber; // derived class but not accessible

    public DerivedClass() {
        DerivedPhoneNumber = PhoneNumber;
    }
}
```

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/KPyXwy
I have made the change, but its not accessible. Not sure why

Comment: It's because PhoneNumber is a Property that you cannot access until the new object is created.

Comment: You can't have access to the field in static context.

Comment: By the way, in C# you can't declare your class as protected.

Comment: That's not a static context. It is a member declaration/initialization. And in there you can't access a Property, because the object itself has not yet been created.

Comment: Yes, and that context will be deemed as static by C#.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't create a new class for your so called access, it completely breaks the inheritance.

Private fields are only accessible from within the declaring class.
Protected fields are accessible from declaring class + all derived classes + extension methods
Internal fields are accessible from declaring class + all derived classes + extension methods within same namespace / assembly (i think)

Furthermore, when thinking about baseclasses/derived classes, think about the modifiers as well, properties/methods that you wish to allow to be modified by base classes should be marked virtual, properties/methods that shouldn't be further extended, should not get the modifiers.

so, baseclass:

```
public class ParentClass
{
    private string userName;
    public virtual string UserName
    {
        get
        {
            return username;
        }
        set
        {
            username = value;
        }
    }

    private string accountNumber; // don't see a reason why it should be a property rather than a field...

    private int userAge;
    internal int UserAge
    {
        get
        {
            return userAge;
        }
        set
        {
            userAge = value;
        }
    }

    protected string phoneNumber;
    public virtual string PhoneNumber
    {
        get
        {
            return phoneNumber;
        }
        set
        {
            phoneNumber = value;
        }
    }

    public ParentClass()
    {
        // potentially do something intresting
    }
}
```

now to make it polymorphic

```
public class DerivedClass : ParentClass
{
    public string CountryCode
    {
        get; set;
    }
    // we can override phoneNumber
    public override string PhoneNumber
    {
        get
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(base.PhoneNumber)) {
                 return base.PhoneNumber;
            }
            if (!base.PhoneNumber.StartsWith(CountryCode)) {
                return CountryCode + base.PhoneNumber;
            }
            return base.PhoneNumber;  // you could also return the field phoneNumber instead (as it is protected)
        }
        set
        {
            base.PhoneNumber = CountryCode + value; // you could also set the field phoneNumber ... (we are adding country code here)
        }
    }

    public DerivedClass() : this("0049")
    {
    }

    public DerivedClass(string countryCode) : base() // call the base constructor as well
    {
        // do something more than what the parentclass is doing, eg...
         this.CountryCode = countryCode;
    }
}
```

Now, in the Derivedclass you could choose to set / return the phonenumber differently, this would mean that all classes that see the ParentClass, can also work with a DerivedClass, and with the same property, but the implementation of that property would be changed by the derived class.

However, your example really doesn't seem clear enough to me, to know what your request is, what you would like to do, and how it should behave.